# Sat watching far on into the night

Tags: prepositions

In my prepositions chapter I found an example sentence

> He sat watching **far on into the night**

I don't understand this bold part

Answer (score 1):

*On* is not here a preposition, but an adverb, acting as an intensifier of "far".

There is a metaphor of "journeying" into the night, so "far on" means "a long way" (on the metaphorical journey into the night).

Comment: He sat watching on into the night. I think this is also correct, isn't it?

Comment: And I think into the night is a phrase meaning at a time that is  very late at night

Comment: @PiyushYadav: yes, you could say that, but I don't think it is very likely, because to my ear "on into the night" would be used with an activity that is either hard, or boring and unwelcome. "Into the night" on its own is not necessarily very late, but refers to an activity carrying on, not to a point of time.